# How to change deltaDecoration colors depending on light/dark theme in monaco-editor

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm using deltaDecorations to highlight some of my text, but their colors need to change depending on whether the theme is light or dark.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

`deltaDecorations` will just set class names on the text spans. It is the job of `css` to map them to styles (colors).

In monaco-editor, all themes that inherit from light theme have a 'vs' class on the root div, and themes that inherit from the dark theme will have 'vs-dark' on the root div.

Thus providing 2 sets of rules for your classes such as

```
.vs .interface {color: blue};
.vs-dark .interface {color: red};
```

Should do the trick.